# Remove hover in show/hide with jQuery on div click

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, show

I have script on my website:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#browse").click(function(){
        $("#navbar-secondary").show();
        $("#navbar-secondary").addClass('animated fadeIn');
    });
});
```

When I click div `id="browse"` it have `:hover/:focus` css style and I want to remove it after click.

What should I do?

Regards!

Comment: Please post your CSS and HTML

Comment: Code should be formatted completely and in a way it is easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the code to see this hard to answer, but are you adding a class on hover/focus? Or is it the browser pseudo class focus that you want to remove?

So, in your css you have element:focus {} and that's causing you the issue?

If so, you could use blur, or remove the class if one is added as suggested above.

Comment: I have pseudo browser class like '.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus'

Comment: try $(this).focus().blur();

Comment: now it works but I have to add new id because hover/focus effect is on the $this>a, how can I do it without adding new id?

Comment: '$(this).find("a").focus().blur();' - is valid?

Answer (score 0):

You can use removeClass

```
$("#browse").click(function(){    
            $("#navbar-secondary").show();
            $("#navbar-secondary").addClass('animated fadeIn');
            $(this).removeClass("yourHoverClassName");
        });
```

Comment: It should be: '$(this).removeClass(":hover :focus");'?

Comment: @mateuszji Nope. What is the class name you applying on hover  or focus ?

Comment: .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus - different than my #browse div.

Comment: could you help me? (;